# which data structure is efficient for key-value pair?

Tags: java, data-structures

```
Key           value
1-5           A
7-10          B
11-15         C
```

if input is 4, output A, input is 8, output is B and so on.
Which data structure i can use to store the following data so the you should not store values multiple times.

I said HashMap, but it is not efficient one.

P.S. i had been asked in interview.

Comment: if it's permitted, you can interchange the key and values, and then use A,B,C as key and store the values a list/set object in your hashmap where you have the 1-5,7-10,11-15 values; although this won't be efficient, but it might serve the purpose here.

Comment: I know where OP is coming from. Interviewers can be really mean sometimes, seldom providing explanation to their own questions and rebuttals.

Comment: BST where you index based on the minimum number, and for each node save the max and the value. Search for the minimum value that is less than or equal to the number you are looking for, see if the max is greater than or equal to your number.

Comment: Use `TreeMap` to store values and store them as `EndingPoint,Value` manner. Then for any key if you want to get value, Call for its `ceilingKey() value` and `floorKey() value` If both are same return it, else return `No value exists!`

Comment: @VinceEmighi didn't ask but hashmap is not efficient for this problem only.

Comment: @SanketMakani seems perfect solution. thanks

Comment: An advice then, always ask a reason, first because it is always good to have a full review to learn from your mistake, but mostly because it is important to show that you are interested and curious ! (But of course you need to be interested and curious ;) )

Comment: @AxelH yeah thanks.

Comment: @Coldspeed you are damn right.

Comment: @srp321 that't not viable to do as it will create problem in retrieval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `TreeMap` to store the values with key being the ending points of the interval. Then retrieve data of `floorKey()` and `ceilingKey()` of any key and if both values are same then return it else return `null`. Each query here requires `O(log n)` time to be answered but the space complexity is very less compared to other approaches. Here I have considered that values are unique for each `interval` and each key has only one value associated with it.

```
TreeMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();

map.put(1,"A"); map.put(5,"A");
map.put(7,"B"); map.put(10,"B");
map.put(11,"C"); map.put(15,"C");

System.out.println(getData(4));
System.out.println(getData(6));
```

---

```
static String getData(int key)
{
    Integer ceiling_key= map.ceilingKey(key);
    Integer floor_key = map.floorKey(key);

    if(ceiling_key == null || floor_key == null)
        return null;

    String value1 = map.get(ceiling_key);
    String value2 = map.get(floor_key);

    if(value1.equals(value2))
        return value1;
    else
        return null;

}
```

**Output :**

```
A
null
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the interviewer was searching for answer of ConcurrentNavigableMap

which can hold several keys with values

In your case:

```
public static NavigableMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    static {
        map.put(1, "A"); // 1..5 => A
        map.put(6, null); // 6  => empty
        map.put(7, "B"); // 7..10 => N
        map.put(11, "C"); // 11..15 => C
        map.put(16, null); // 16.. => empty
    }
```

and then get value with

```
map.floorEntry(4).getValue()
```

Comment: Intersting implementation, but please note that you need to use `NavigableMap.floorEntry` to get the value as a "range" an not `Map.get`. By the way, just digging a bit more, this is a feature from `NavigableMap` that is implemented by `TreeMap`, no need to use a class that specific.

Comment: updated solution. interview question seems to ask about a range of keys

Comment: @user7294900 nice one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As keys are not repeated you can use index of array as key:

```
int[] array = {0,A,A,A,A,A,0,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,C,C,};
```

Now at `array[1] - array[5]` there is value `A` and at `array[7] - array[10]`
value is `B`

Comment: can't use this, multiple time storing values was not allowed.